# Fire Map event whenever a MapItem event is fired (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

I am currently programming a little WPF app, where I desire to draw some simple shapes on a WPF Map control.

For drawing my shapes, I use a MapItemsControl and a few MapPolyline objects.

However, if I, for example, click directly on a MapPolyline, the MouseDown or MouseUp event of the MapPolyline is fired.

How can I change this behavior, so that the corresponding events of the Map control are fired?

Background: I want to use the MouseDoubleClick event, which is missing in the MapPolyline class.

Comment: How about setting `IsEnabled` or `IsHitTestVisible` to `false` on the MapPolylines?

Comment: Well, the wonders of WPF - setting IsHitTestVisible to false works.
Post an answer and get your reputation. (:

Comment: Here we go. You might also be interested in [this](http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/). No API key required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply set the `IsEnabled` or the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the MapPolylines to `false`.